# Limit 1 route to leaflet L.Routing.control

Tags: javascript, leaflet, routing

I'm using the leaflet-routing library https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/releases/tag/v3.1.1

How can I limit the amount of routes the L.Routing.control returns.

I'm using this code:

```
fDirectionService = new L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        new L.latLng(-27.1216666667, -52.6213888889),
        new L.latLng(-27.5963, -48.5491)
    ]
}).addTo(map).on('routesfound', function(e) {
    console.log(e.routes); // e.routes have length 2
});
```

After the 'routesfound' event it returns 2 routes (fDirectionService._routes.length == 2)

Can I request only one? Or at least hide all except the first?

[image: L.Routing.control with two routes]

Edit: There is an option showAlternatives: http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/ but even that doesn't work.

Edit 2: Days and nobody answered, that's odd. Anyway, I've tested with Mapbox e with the same coordinates it returns only one route, could it be that it must be configured on the server side only?